# Write loop into pythonic way

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dict array that stores audits for tickets. Each audit has an information of `user_id`, `date` that happens changes and a `list of events` and each event has a few attributes like `type`, `field name`, among others.

Based on those informations, I need to extract events information based on `date` and convert to another dict. Note: I need to keep only the last event for each `field_name`.

I've wrote a "super" loop that does what I need but this code looks pretty weird and not optmized:

dict sample:

```
data = {
    "audits": [
        "id": 1234,
            "ticket_id": 1111,
            "created_at": "2019-04-07T01:09:40Z",
            "author_id": 9876543,           
            "events": [{
                    "id": 1234,
                    "type": "Random"
                },
                {
                    "id": 765456,
                    "type": "Create",
                    "value": "Lovely form",
                    "field_name": "subject"
                },              
                {
                    "id": 356765,
                    "type": "Create",
                    "value": None,
                    "field_name": "priority"
                },              
                {
                    "id": 2345432,
                    "type": "Change",                   
                    "value": "normal",
                    "field_name": "priority",
                    "previous_value": None
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

code:

```
field_history = []

for audit in data['audits']:
    user_id = audit['author_id']
    updated = audit['created_at']

    base_info = {
        'user_id': user_id,
        'updated': updated
    }

    # Iterate to get distinct value (last found on dict)
    fields = [d for d in audit['events'] if (d['type'] == 'Create' or d['type'] == 'Change') and d['field_name'] != 'tags']        
    updated_fields = [] # this list is being used to keep history by updated
    for field in fields:
        distincts = [d for d in audit['events'] if d.get('field_name', '') == field['field_name']]        
        distinct = distincts[-1]
        # remove older values and keep only the last one found on list
        updated_fields[:] = [d for d in updated_fields if d['updated'] == updated and d.get('field_name') != distinct['field_name']]
        updated_fields.append({**base_info, **distinct}) # add always the last element on list

    field_history = field_history + updated_fields
```

What is the proper way to write this loop making it optimized to handle large datasets?

Comment: Check out [codereview.se]

Comment: @SmartManoj - This is still a question potentially suitable for [so]

Comment: For the given example, what events and output are you expecting? `[2345432, 765456, 1234]`?

Comment: "*What is the proper way to write this loop?*" is not a proper question for Stack Overflow. It is both too broad and opinion-based. Do you have any specific question? If not, you should migrate/post your post on Code Review instead

Comment: @Sayse output should be a list of `{**base_info, **distinct}`

Answer (score 0):

I like to start by making some simple functions to handle the transformations and filtering to allow the top level to remain clean:

```
def event_valid(event):
    return (
        event['type'] in ('Create', 'Change')
        and event['field_name'] not in ('tags',)
    )

events = [event for event in audit['events'] if event_valid(event)]

# Assuming the list is ordered... If not then sort it before next statement
# This trick filters to only the latest event for each distinct field_name
events = {
    event['field_name']: event for event in events
}.values()

return {
    'user_id': audit['author_id'],
    'updated': audit['created_at'],
    'events': events,
}
```